# What are the steps to create patchset in git

Tags: git, github

So I want to create a patchset - total 3 different patches for a code fix. Its a `git` based project.

I have thought following steps-

1. I am in `master` branch. Did by `git checkout master` Create 3
   different branches - `git branch First`, `git branch Second` and
   `git branch Third`
2. Do changes (Code fix 1) in `First` branch. Then
   create patch 1 with `master` and `First`.
3. Do changes (Code fix 2) in
   `Second.` branch. Then create patch 2 with `master` and `Second`.
4. And similarly for third fix.

It is important to note that all the code changes for all the 3 patches are in a single `.c` file. Also, I cant make a single patch of all the code fix - I have to make 3 different patches - this is a requirement.

Actually the patches should be independent - patch 1 can be applied by developer 1 at some commit hash, patch 2 can be applied by another developer at another different commit hash - and similarly for dev 3.

I am confident that there is a way to create the 3 patches using only a single branch. Kindly illuminate.

Comment: Are the patches dependent on each other?

Comment: @Mureinik. I am sorry - what do you exactly mean by dependent? The 3 patches dont have anything overlapping. Actually my code fix is just big so I have to split the BIG patch into 3

Comment: Whether or not the code overlaps isn't the issue. Does patch 2 need any functionality from patch 1? Would it work without it? Is there any logical relation between the three patches?

Comment: patch 2 doesn't need any functionality from patch 1.... similarly patch 3 doesn't need any functionality from patch 2

Comment: So, what's the problem? If they all are the last patches in their respective branches, run `for br in First Second Third; do git format-patch -v1 -N1 $br; done`. Otherwise you need to do it via temporary branch where you *fast forward* merge all branches, and run `git format-patch -v1 -n3 HEAD~0`.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you probably don't need three branches for this - just one (let's call it "my-feature"), branched out from master. Then create the first patch there, the second patch **on top of the first**, and the third **on top of the second**. Then, push the branch for review.

**EDIT:**
Following the clarification in the comments - since the three patches are completely independent, having three unrelated branches would be the right way to go.

Comment: Thank you for answering - but actually I want to create the patches independently - like patch 1 can be applied by developer 1 at some commit hash, patch 2 by other developer at another commit hash - and similarly for dev 3.